Struggling to Understand Householder Arnoldi Algorithm
I've spent at least two frustrating weeks of trying and failing to understand the Householder Arnoldi algorithm. I understand the basic Gram-Schmidt Arnoldi algorithm and the maths of Householder transformations, unfortunately I find the description of the Householder Arnoldi (Algorithm 6.3) in "Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems" by Yousef Saad to be most unclear. The steps 4 and 5 do not seem to be identical to the medium article that I linked.
One of the most confusing aspects is that I cannot quite tell from the reading of the algorithm whether the the Householder unit vector is formed from the product of the previous Householder reflection transformation matrices $P_i$ and the input or RHS matrix $A$, i.e. $P_{k-1} \ldots P_1 A$.
I wish I had a worked example. It would clear up the confusion.
